# routing audio data from c application to virtual audio driver in mac os

Tags: macos, core-audio, hal

I'm trying to create an application in mac os which does below:

1. START/STOP capturing/rendering on default-microphone/default-speaker based on Virtual Mic/Speaker being used by any of the audio application like audacity, zoom, skype and etc
2. Read default-microphone data, writes/forward to virtual microphone ring buffer to work for real-time streaming.
3. Get virtual speaker’s data and playback on default-speaker phone.
   Expecting My application to be on C/c++ code.

using some open source code I'm able create virtual mic/speaker device. How can I invoke driver from my application code to route the data.

Previously , we developed virtual audio driver for windows , there we used ioctl to transfer the data to virtual driver .In MAC OS , Is there any method similar to ioctl's in windows.

Can anyone please help me which method I have to use.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, clarify your question: are you interested in how to invoke the driver? Are you programming on MacOs? Why are you asking if there is something similar to Ioctl in Microsoft Windows if you are working on MacOs?

Comment: Hi David,Thanks for the quick reply...
are you interested in how to invoke the driver? Yes, i want to invoke virtual audio driver from application and would like to read the real microphone data and route it to virtual driver .
As I'm very new to MAC OS , I mentioned about windows IOCTL for reference(which I used earlier). It would be great if you can help me out in this.

Comment: And I'm looking for any kind of core audio API's available to stream the data from real hardware to virtual mic